# Changing WordPress URL structure - Redirects

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I'm changing my URL structure from domain.com/postname to domain.com/type/postname

What's the best way to redirect? I tried using the Redirection plugin, but it seems that I need to redirect each URL manually. Is there any way to redirect all the posts at once?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the wp-admin's dashboard using domain.com/wp-admin. Then look for the Settings-->Permalinks option. From this page you can change the URL settings for all of your posts.

Comment: Does that just switch to the URLs or does it also redirect people who visit the old URLs?

Comment: Yes, it also redirect people who visit the old URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some instructions on how to redirect your sites url.
[Changing the site url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

Back up your site first if you still can? When I changed to pretty permalinks I had to include a forward slash to custom field images.

```
from:  wp-content/uploads/2012/08/tulip-813-01.jpg

to:    /wp-content/uploads/2012/08/tulip-813-01.jpg
```